# Child process runs in normal priority only. Why?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, performance, scheduled-task

I run a scheduled task in Windows Server 2008 R2. I used the technique described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/151824/process-runs-slower-as-a-scheduled-task-than-it-does-interactively)
to set its priority to high priority (level 1 of 7).
My task runs a process (an EXE file) that creates child process during run-time (another EXE file).

My problem is that the child process gets normal priority only. I'd expect the child process to get high priority as well. I couldn't find out how to do it. Do you know about it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your child process launched as normal priority was answered in this post [Process Priority Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619543/process-priority-inheritance)