# Why does Windows artificially throttle low priority processes during low overall utilization?

Tags: windows, performance

We have noticed that programs that run via Task Scheduler perform worse than when launched by the user. [It seems others have noticed this too](https://serverfault.com/questions/151824/process-runs-slower-as-a-scheduled-task-than-it-does-interactively). It's apparently because by default, Task Scheduler runs programs at a lower priority. Changing the priority confirms it: the programs perform as they should.

Intuitively this would make sense if other things were going on in the system: higher priority programs get their turn first, and then whatever is left, to consume all of the machines resources. But this isn't the case: our server isn't doing anything else. This background task is effectively the only thing running, and yet it's reading from disk and transfering over the network at a small fraction of what it's capable of. This might make sense if we were talking about a laptop (need to conserve battery), but we're talking about Windows Server 2019 here (aka Windows 10 1809).

**Why doesn't Windows consume its resources to the fullest if nothing is competing for them?**

Comment: Do you want something different to "because they designed their task scheduler like this"? Because that's what they did, I _think_ from Server 2008 (R2) onwards.

Comment: @Lenniey Maybe. Do you know of any resources where they say this?

Comment: [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/tasksettings-priority): _The priority level (0-10) of the task. The default is 7._ and: _Priority level 0 is the highest priority, and priority level 10 is the lowest priority. The default value is 7. Priority levels 7 and 8 are used for background tasks, and priority levels 4, 5, and 6 are used for interactive tasks._ and [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/ProcThread/scheduling-priorities)

Comment: Those links don't explain why Windows won't use all of its resources when only lower-priority processes are running.

Comment: Perhaps they want to have some cores/threads that are ready for immediate execution for more critical tasks that may arise at any unknown moment from user input or other things happening? Just a theory since I don't know of any better answer.